# Fog of War in Unity

Tags: unity, c#, shaders, fog-of-war

I know that my question will not fall into the type of questions normally asked here (no coding presented). I just need some tips and advise on how to proceed (e.g. pipeline or something).

I'm making a game that will have a fog of war. The thing is that I need something like the X-COM fog of war, which seems to look like a 3D fog of war and not the plane (maybe I'm wrong though). I understand something about shaders (only 2D though). But I'm not getting how to proceed with this matter.

Does anyone know how it's being done or, maybe, is there some reading, or a specific topic I need to cover? I'd appreciate any tip on the matter.

Thanks in advance!

The only similarly looking example that I found was from this stack exchange topic and I was thingking of combining it with the X-COM-fog-of-war ish thing:
[image]
But the idea is a bit different, everithing must be visible except for enemy units and the area that is not visible (where the enemy units are not visible) at all should be black and white(not coloured).

P.S.: I'm a bit new to this, so I did read some posts about it here. But there were only parts of the process. A kind of a step-by-step answer would be really nice to get.

Comment: We have non-code questions here fairly frequently. What you can do instead is include examples of the effect you're trying to achieve.

Comment: I see your example is quite hard-edged, but I thought I remembered X-COM's fog being quite soft and, well, foggy. Can you confirm which of these looks you're going for?

Comment: @DMGregory I'ts not my example, I saw it here. That's why I added some explanation for what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: It's the only visual you've added to the question at present. If you're looking for a different visual appearance, can you please add an image of what you want it to look like?